# Google Play Games v2, Missing GamesResolutionActivity error

Tags: android, google-play-games

I'm trying to integrate Google Play Games Services into my android game for a high score leaderboard. I followed the quickstart guide [[1](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart)] and the documentation on sign in [[2](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/signin)].

What is stated there is that the sign in happens automatically. The only thing required is to initialize the SDK via `PlayGamesSdk.initialize(activity);` in the `OnCreated` handler of the main activity.
This is also my experience when using other games. I get a prompt to sign in using the play games account.

However what happens with my game is I get an Exception followed by a crash:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {org.mygame.android/com.google.android.gms.games.internal.v2.resolution.GamesResolutionActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

I can't find any info about that. What am I missing?

Note: if I use the Play Games app to manually sign-in for my game before starting it, everything works: I can query the sign-in status, user-id and show the leaderboard without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add the following snippet to the AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<activity
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.internal.v2.resolution.GamesResolutionActivity"
  android:exported="false">
</activity>
```